# What is this dime sized black bug with white on the segments near Loveland Colorodao?

Tags: bug-identification, colorado

On my walk around town today I found this small black bug, (keychain carabiner for scale).

[image]

Closeup

[image]

It has two antenna and it seems that there is white on the edge of the segments.

Does anyone know what kind of bug this is?

Comment: DIIK, but it is either a bug that is essential to the local ecology or bug that hitchhiked on a shipment from elsewhere that is a disaster for the local ecology.  In other words, an important question.

Comment: Where are you from that you've never seen one of these?  I thought they were ubiquitous.  (Serious question)

Comment: @msouth I have seen them before just thought I would ask what they are exactly

Comment: I have about 5000 of them in my compost bin.

Comment: OK gotcha, the question struck me as someone asking who'd never seen one before, which was amazing to me because I think I've seen them everywhere I've lived in the US.  Did you know they breathe using gills?  (I had four boys, we were trying to figure out how to keep them alive as "pets".  Did not succeed at this but learned a bit about them :D ).

Comment: The "white on the segments" are just reflection highlights?

Comment: @WeatherVane I added a closeup, I don't think so

Comment: Not enough white to be *Armadillidium maculatum* I don't think

Comment: Did you take this pic?  Why not enter it in the current contest?

Answer (score 17):

Probably a woodlouse which is a type of crustacean in the suborder Oniscidea.

[image]

Source: [a-z animals](https://a-z-animals.com/animals/woodlouse/)

They are globally distributed, except in polar regions and arid deserts, and are also known by the following names:

> - "armadillo bug"
> - "boat-builder" (Newfoundland, Canada)
> - "butcher boy" or "butchy boy" (Australia,mostly around Melbourne)
> - "carpenter" or "cafner" (Newfoundland and Labrador, Canada)
> - "cheeselog" (Reading, England)
> - "cheesy bobs" (Guildford, England)
> - "cheesy bug" (North West Kent, England)
> - "chiggy pig" (Devon, England)
> - "chucky pig" (Devon, Gloucestershire, Herefordshire, England)
> - "doodlebug" (also used for the larva of an antlion)
> - "gramersow" (Cornwall, England)
> - "granny grey" (South Wales)
> - "hog-louse"
> - "monkey-peas" (Kent, England)
> - "monk's louse" (transl. "munkelus", Norway)
> - "pea bug" or "peasie-bug" (Kent, England)
> - "pill bug" (usually applied only to the genus Armadillidium)
> - "potato bug"
> - "roll up bug"
> - "roly-poly"
> - "sow bug"
> - "slater" (Scotland, Northern Ireland, New Zealand and Australia)
> - "wood bug" (British Columbia, Canada)

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse)

Comment: I had no idea these had so many names and occupied so many regions of the world!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: maybe because the official name is terrible.

Comment: @Joshua I think you mean "lousy".

Comment: The one in this photo seems to be a '78 model. The OP clearly posted a pre-'74 model.

Answer (score 7):

I see these everywhere where I live (Central Texas). We usually call them "pill bugs" or "rollie-polies" (usu. young children).

It shouldn't do you or anything you own any harm; they mostly just crawl around on things and roll up into a ball when you touch them. Kids would always run around collecting them when I was in school.

Comment: While I agree that these guys are not dangerous to people or pets, and are *generally* helpful in the garden, they will absolutely massacre any strawberries or plant seedlings they come across.  Apparently they also [ringbark seedlings](https://www.abc.net.au/gardening/factsheets/slater-control/9430670)

Comment: @mcalex Well, I'd expect this question was mostly about camping/hiking, and very few hikers carry seedlings or garden with them.

Answer (score 3):

This is a terrestrial [isopod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopoda) [crustacean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crustacean) called a woodlouse ([colloquially referred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse#Common_names) to as pill bugs, potato bugs, roly-pollies, sow bugs, etc.).

[image]

There are over 5000 species in the world with at least 64 in Russia (see [Kuznetsova & Gongalsky 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3335401/)).

**Habitat**:

Woodlice are typically found in damp, dark places -- in the soil, under rocks/logs/debris, etc.

> Living in a terrestrial environment, woodlice breathe through trachea-like lungs in their paddle-shaped hind legs (pleopods), called pleopodal lungs. Woodlice need moisture because they rapidly lose water by excretion and through their cuticle, and so are usually found in damp, dark places

**Description**:

As with all arthropods, the woodlouse is a segmented animal with a rigid exoskeleton and jointed limbs.

- However, this is *not* an insect! Insects have 3 pairs of legs while isopods have 7 pairs of legs.

The extended uropods on your specimen as well as the pereon-pleon junction, number of antenna flagella, etc. all are important for IDing to species. (E.g., see [here](http://pick4.pick.uga.edu/mp/20q?guide=Oniscidea&flags=col4:gleansubgenus)).

Note: although many people associate these arthropods with the ability to roll up into a perfect ball, only woodlice in the genus Armadillidium and in the family Armadillidae can roll up into an almost perfect sphere as a defensive mechanism.

**Diet**:

Woodlice are generally [detritivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detritivore), meaning they eat decaying organic matter.

---

Citations:

<sup>Kuznetsova, Daria M., and Konstantin B. Gongalsky. "Cartographic analysis of woodlice fauna of the former USSR." ZooKeys 176 (2012): 1.</sup>